# How to hide page name in rewrite rules in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to hide page name from url using rewrite rules in Nginx. but its not working, please see the below example

Actual url: `https://super30.net/referal.php?uid=999999`
Needed url: `https://super30.net/999999`

I tried below code

```
location = / {
      rewrite ^/referal/(.*)$ /referal.php?uid=$1 last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `=`.

If you set `location = /` the only URL that matches this block is `/` and nothing else. Remove the `=`.

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/referal/(.*)$ /referal.php?uid=$1 last;
}
```